# Themes don't apply on activity

Tags: android, android-activity

To apply a theme on an activity, you have to add the theme from (Manefest file)
 like this:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Forth"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_forth"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

The app starts normally, but when I click the button to stat the (dialog activity), the app fall-down/?

and when I remove the theme `(android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog")`,

the app works perfectly.

Please provide me with solution for this problem. I am running Android Studio 1.1.0

Comment: What do you mean by "fall down"? If the app crashes, there is an exception in logcat; please post the stacktrace of the exception here.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I just solved it. It's because my Activity was inheriting from ActionBarActivity. I make it inherit from Activity and now it's working.